# Get activity context in click listener callback

Tags: java, android

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
final int SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE =1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(checkPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)){
                    SmsManager smqr = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smqr.sendTextMessage("000000000", null, "Message", null, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }

            private boolean checkPermission(String permission) {
         int check = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,permission);
         return (check == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

i have wrote this code to make a simple app to send msgs to phone numbers , in the android studio it puts red lines under the "this" i am not sure why
thanks in advance

Comment: You have to pass *Activity Context* their not a *view click listener context*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)), `checkSelfPermission` requires a `context` as first parameter, in your code you are passing an instance of `View.OnClickListener`, which obviously is not a `context`.

`this` should be your activity, not the click listener.

Refactor your code this way:

```java
private boolean checkPermission(String permission) {
  int check = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission);
  return (check == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```

Comment: done <3 , i have a little question if you have time to answer it when i send a msg it only sends the msg to the number i put in the code , is there a way or a function to make it send to any number i put in the app itself or maybe i should make it read saved contacts on the phone , thanks again

Comment: @legendarychild it's quite complex to respond in a comment to this question, but basically if you want to pick a contact from the contact list on your phone you need to define a contact intent. You can find a well detailed documentation about it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#PickContact

Answer (score 2):

You need a context, `this` inside the `Interface` refers to the interface itself and not to the `activity`context.

Use bellow code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Context context;
final int SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE =1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(checkPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)){
                    SmsManager smqr = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smqr.sendTextMessage("000000000", null, "Message", null, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},SEND_SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }

            private boolean checkPermission(String permission) {
         int check = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,permission);
         return (check == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

            }
        });


    }
}
```